# Can zeros of a polynomial form a structure?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Given a polynomial P in 1 variable over a division ring D (by polynomial, we allow arbitrary expression, so even something like $jX^{2}kX^{4}$ is allowed, ie. you don't have put put coefficient on one side). If the roots of this is finite, or everything, it is possible for them to form a subfield or subring. But if the roots are infinite but not everything, is it possible for the roots to form any sort of substructure at all? Subring, multiplicative subgroup, anything.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the roots are infinite but not everything"?  Sorry, I think your question desperately needs some editing and clarification.

Comment: @ErickWong: I'm not sure what is wrong here; $x-1$ for example have 1 roots, so that is not infinite, and $0$ have everything as roots.

Comment: Ah I see you wrote division ring and not field.  Do you have some examples of what you have in mind as a substructure in the finite case?

Comment: @ErickWong: boring example, but you can just take $D=\overline{F_{p}}$ and $P=x^{p}-x$. This substructure is a field. Or $x-1$ in $\mathbb{H}$, which is a trivial multiplicative subgroup.

Comment: Okay, so it seems like your question is more "is there a polynomial whose roots coincide with a multiplicative/additive substructure of infinite cardinality (other than the entire ring)?".  The way it's phrased, it looked more like you wanted to impose some nebulously-defined structure on the roots of an arbitrary polynomial ("Given a polynomial...")